# Simplifying $\sqrt{a^{4 n}} \cdot \frac{3}{a^{n}} \cdot a^{1+n} \cdot(2 a)^{3 n-1}$ as far as possible, using only positive integers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So far here is my steps but I am unsure of how to do the final step

$$\sqrt{a^{4 n}} \cdot \frac{3}{a^{n}} \cdot a^{1+n} \cdot(2 a)^{3 n-1}$$

$$\left(a^{4 n}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \cdot \frac{3 a}{a^{n}} \cdot a^{1+n} \cdot a \cdot \frac{(2 a)^{3 n}}{2 a}
$$

by canceling the a's we therefore get

$$ \frac{a^{2 n} \cdot 3 \cdot 2^{3 n} \cdot(a)^{3 n}}{2} $$

How would you then express this in all positive integers

Comment: You are almost there.  Simplify the product of the powers of $a$ using the summation-of-powers, and then divide $2^{3n}$ by 2 using the subtraction-of-powers rule.

Comment: I think I have my final answer, is it a^5n x 2^3n x 1.5?

Comment: Well, you got $a^{5n}$ right. When you said "only using positive integers", I assumed that you meant the answer shouldn't have decimals. So while your answer is technically right, it has a "1.5". If you want to remove the decimal you could keep the 3 and do $\frac{2^{3n}}{2}$. But if you're fine with decimals, then your right. Nice job!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to clarify the comments, I have a full worked solution provided.

\begin{align}
&\quad\sqrt{a^{4n}} \cdot \frac{3}{a^{n}} \cdot a^{1+n} \cdot(2 a)^{3 n-1}\\
&=\left(a^{4n}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot3\cdot\frac{1}{a^n}\cdot a^{1+n}\cdot2^{3n-1}\cdot a^{3n-1}\\
&=a^{\frac{4n}{2}}\cdot3\cdot a^{-n}\cdot a^{n+1}\cdot2^{3n-1}\cdot a^{3n-1}\\
&=3\cdot a^{2n}\cdot a^{-n}\cdot a^{n+1}\cdot2^{3n-1}\cdot a^{3n-1}\\
&=3\cdot2^{3n-1}\cdot a^{2n-n+(n+1)+(3n-1)}\\
&=3\cdot2^{3n-1}\cdot a^{2n-n+n+1+3n-1}\\
&=3\cdot2^{3n-1}\cdot a^{5n}\\
&=\frac{3}{2}a^{5n}\cdot2^{3n}
\end{align}

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer That is true, and I only did that in the last step - technically the answer should be the second last line

Comment: Ah, didn't see it, the bigger the fool me! Thanks for the clarification.